# onActivated Event Handler not recognised in WPF Prism application

Tags: c#, wpf

We are trying to parse command line args when our Prism 8 WPF app is launched using protocol activation. The following method is not recognised in App.xaml.cs

```
 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
```

This is specifically for the case when the app is already running. The other issue is how to forward the information to Viewmodels from this method. we have included the below using statement. Is there some other way we should be able to intercept this event?

```
 using Windows.UI.Notifications;
```

We have also tried calling
AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs()
However the arguments length is always zero

```
    private void MainWindow_Activated(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var args = AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();
        switch (args.Kind)
        {
            case ActivationKind.Launch:
                var launchargs = args as LaunchActivatedEventArgs;
                var num = launchargs.Arguments.Length;
                break;
            case ActivationKind.ToastNotification:

                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: In WPF, you need to define a custom `OnActivated` and call it yourself once you have retrieved the `IActivatedEventArgs` from the package.

Comment: "once you have retrieved the IActivatedEventArgs from the package" Not sure how to do that

Comment: So you haven't actually implemented any protocol activation?

Comment: Yes we have, when the app is not already active we get the args using Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(), there aren't any IActivatedEventArgs here

Comment: If the app is already launched Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() does not give us the parameters

Comment: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` has nothing to do with protocol activation. You need to pack your app to be able to use `IActivatedEventArgs`.